# How to import LinkedIn Json file into Hive External Table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

The following is the JSON file exported from LinkedIn using API.

```
{
   "numResults": 21,
   "people":  
             {  "total": 21,
                 "values":
                         {    "firstName": "Kshitiz",
                              "headline": "Interbank Derivatives  Bank Treasury",
                               "id": "aK8sji3rN7",
                               "industry": "Financial Services",
                               "lastName": "Jain",
                               "locations": {"country": {"code": "in"},
                               "name": "Mumbai Area, India"
                                            },
                               "numConnections": 500,
                               "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licT5WVdExyDEYDzE6cp0VwZ"
                          }
             }
```

}

Saved the above json document in a text file and imported into hadoop directory /sample.

An external table is created using the following command. JAR file for serde is also added.

```
create external table linkedi(numResults int,people Struct<total:int,values:Struct<firstName:String,headline:String,id:String,industry:String,lastName:String,locations:Struct<country:Struct<code:String>,name:String>,numConnections:int,pictureUrl:String>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde' location '/sample';
```

When running `select statement ( select * from linkedi;)` it shows the following error.

> OK
>   Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>   Time taken: 0.213 seconds

What is the reason for showing the error? Is there any error in the structure of the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SerDe you are using does not support nested JSON. You can try to flatten the JSON first or
Try to use: 
[hive-json-serde.googlecode.com/files/hive-json-serde-0.2.jar](http://hive-json-serde.googlecode.com/files/hive-json-serde-0.2.jar)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same trouble. Panshul is right, Apache's SerDe does not support nested JSON. But still I was not able to work with the "hive-json-serde-0.2.jar", at least not with the last version of Hive.

I found the best way is to use Openx's SerDe lib. In short, **the working JAR** is json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar which can be found [here](http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3/cdh5/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar). This one is working with 'STRUCT' and can even ignore some malformed JSON. During the creation of the table, include the following code:

```
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
 LOCATION ...
```

If needed, it is possible to recompile it from [here](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) or [here](https://github.com/sheetaldolas/Hive-JSON-Serde/tree/master). I tried the first repository and it is compiling fine for me, after adding the necessary libs. The repository has also been updated recently.

Check for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785117/where-is-the-syntax-error-on-this-simple-hive-query-with-struct/32799551#32799551).

Comment: It would be great if you could post the relevant parts of the answer here, in case that link were to go dead.